# Digital sound out dissapears when connecting Creative Live! Cam Chat

Tags: sound, webcam, spdif

I tried the cam and the digital out signal dissapears when connecting the cam. Everything is fine when i unplug it. I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits, same problem.

In sound settings outputs, everything dissapears except analog out when connecting the cam.

Does anyone have a clue for what i can do to fix this problem. In Windows i use Google to find the solution to problems like this. But with Linux i can not figure out witch solution to use, ending messing up things.

Comment: Maybe i should try to install the latest distro? I have been looking at other webcams, but there is only the Creative cams that looks good enough to a resonable price to have on top of my tv. There is a later version of this cam also, but i would bet the problem is with this one to. I found a logitech cam also, but searching the web it seems like the driver is propiatary and i see people have problems making this work.